# wildcards to download particular csv

Tags: r, csv, web, web-scraping, download

Still very new to R, so please excuse me.

I am trying to download csv data from the Sloane Digital Website Survey.  Within R I do the following -

```
astro1 <- read.csv("https://dr14.sdss.org/optical/spectrum/view/data/format=csv/spec=full?mjd=55359&fiberid=596&plateid=4055")
```

This downloads 1 csv spectra per fibre ID per plate [here, plateid=4055].  However, if there are several hundred fibre IDs it will be a very long couple of days.

1. Is there a way to batch download all csv data for all fibre IDs?  I tried `fibreid=*` (and "", " ", @, but got the following error -

   "no lines available in input", or unexpected string constant.
2. If for example there are 100 .csv files per plate.  All will have a common x-axis (wavelength), but a different 3rd column (best fit, for y-axis).  Is there a way to get the downloaded csv tables to form 1 very large dataset, with the same common axis (wavelength), and subsequent columns to show only the Best Fit columns?

Many thx

Comment: Can you get a list of all the files you need together? That way you could loop through the files to download. As of 2, yes, loop read everything then then use a join to make a single table. How exactly to do this will depend on the format of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Best case would be that you have a list of all the links to your wanted csv-Files. Since this is  seemingly not the case, you know that you want to loop over all the `fiberid`s. You know the structure of the link, hence we could use it to define

```
buildFibreIdLink <- function(fibreId) {
  paste0("https://dr14.sdss.org/optical/spectrum/view/data/format=csv/spec=full?mjd=55359&fiberid=",fibreId,"&plateid=4055")
}
```

Now I would just loop over all ids, whatever all means in this case. Just start at 1 and count up. Therefore I would use the function

```
getCsvDataList <- function(startId = 1, endId = 10, maxConsecutiveNulls = 5) {
  
  dataList <- list()
  consecutiveNullCount <- 0
  
  for(id in startId:endId) {
    csvLink <- buildFibreIdLink(fibreId = id)
    newData <- tryCatch(expr = {
      read.csv(csvLink)
    }, error = function(e) {return(NULL)})
    if(is.null(newData)) {
      consecutiveNullCount <- consecutiveNullCount +1
    } else {
      dataList <- c(dataList,list(newData))
      consecutiveNullCount <- 0
    }
    if(consecutiveNullCount == maxConsecutiveNulls) {
      print(paste0("reached maxConsecutiveNulls at id ",id))
      break;
    }
  }
  
  return(dataList)
}
```

Specify the id-range you want to read, such that you can really partially read the csvs. Now the question is: When have you reached the end? My answer would basically be: You reached the end, when there are `maxConsecutiveNulls` consecutive "read-csv-fails". I assume that a link doesn't exist if you can't read it, hence the `tryCatch`-block triggers and I basically count these triggers until a given maximum.

If you know that the structure of the csvs is always the same, you can merge the list of data.frames together via

```
dataListFrom1to10 <- getCsvDataList(startId = 1, endId = 10)
merged1to10 <- do.call("rbind",dataListFrom1to10)
```

Update: If you have your vector of needed fibre-ids, you can modify the function as follows. Since we didn't know the exact Ids, we looped from 1 to anywhere. Now, knowing the Ids, you can replace the `startId` and `endId` arguments by say `fibreIdVector`, to get the signature
`getCsvDataList <- function(fibreIdVector, maxConsecutiveNulls) ...`. In the `for`-loop, replace `for(id in startId:endId)` by `for(id in fibreIdVector)`. If you know that all your Ids are valid, you can remove the error-handling to get a much cleaner function. Since you don't need to know the results of previous iterations, e.g. counting the `consecutiveNullCount`, you can just put everything into an `lapply` like

```
allCsvData <- lapply(fibreIdVector, function(id) {
  read.csv(buildFibreIdLink(fibreId = id))
})
```

replacing the whole function.

Comment: The use of `tryCatch` makes this very general and useful.  In this case, the number of fibers is known, depending on telescope architecture, [SDSS fibre](https://www.sdss.org/dr12/spectro/spectro_basics) FiberID:    an integer denoting the fiber number (1 to 640 for SDSS-I/II; 1 to 1000 for BOSS). Will employ this approach as indicated.

Comment: Thank you all for sharing your insights, very much appreciated.

Comment: Jonas, with some digging around and the luxury of hindsight,  I have found a way to specify the fibreIDs needed.  As befits my neophyte status, I can generate an excel csv table with the fibre IDs needed - this could be up to 150 such numbers.  Can the buildFibreIDlink and subsequent code be easily modified to read such a table?

Comment: In case you haven't figured it out on your own until yet, I have updated the answer now.

Comment: Hi Jonas, this is way beyond what I have seen before, it will take me a couple of days to work through it, thx

Comment: @Jonas, if I had the critical skills I would work on developing a system to allow me to select fibreID subject to certain criteria.  That could be a body of work for myself at some stage in the future.  For now, the method you proposed is more than sufficient for my learning.  Thx again.